# Does AWS RDS have 'Automatic Scaling' or 'Load Balancing' Feature?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Is there feature in RDS to 'autoscaling' or 'load balancing' like EC2? If not, how do you determine if you have the right RDS instance? If there's no "load balancer" how do RDS handle sudden spike?

Comment: No, as people mentioned below, you can have read replicas (but it's not done automatically). But if you have write spikes, you have to provision the master instance to be big enough to handle the spikes.

Answer (score 0):

there is concept called read replica to distribute traffic to different database replica for highly consumed website.

Developer can create replica different region wise and create load balancer to distribute traffic.

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot put multiple independent databases behind a load balancer, and send each request to different database instance as this will arise question of synchronization among database instances.
But yes you can scale your RDS instance vertically and horizontally quit easily.
[this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/scaling-your-amazon-rds-instance-vertically-and-horizontally/) link will help you do it.